# Unity/C# Adding two areas presented by vector2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, addition, area

I have two areas, which are both given in there bounds.size. Now the z-axis does not matter for me, since i am working in 2D. I want to add these vectors so i have a vector, which represents the jointed area. Simply adding these vectors does not work.

Comment: How are the areas supposed to be added? By x component, by y component, or by some combination of both? There are many ways to put together two rectangles. For example, if you have (2, 1) and (1, 1), the resultant area could be (3, 1), but could also be (2, 1.5). Both yield the same total area.

Comment: The way doesnt matter, in the end i will calculate the bounds.size of it, the only thing that matters is that the New area is equally big as the two combined

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the combined area of two rectangles `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, then take

```
float totalArea = (x1 * y1) + (x2 * y2)
```

which is literally just summing the areas of the two rectangles. If you need a rectangle with that area and don't care what shape the rectangle is, just choose

```
Vector2 rect = new Vector2(Mathf.sqrt(totalArea), Mathf.sqrt(totalArea))
```

Which is a square whose area is equal to the sum of the areas of the two rectangles. (I don't know what you plan on doing with this vector. It is completely arbitrary and is not a particularly meaningful value, since there are an infinite number of possible rectangles with any given `totalArea`. If you just want the sum of the areas, you'd be better off storing it as a float.)